# How to join model in xmlrpc using ripcord?

Tags: php, odoo, ripcord

I have 2 model : `product.template` and `product.brand`.
i want to show detail data from product.template and its brand which the brand i can get from product.brand's model. In model product.brand contain product_id which have relation with id in product.template. Here's my current code. This code only showing data from product.template.

```
<?php    
$products = $ripcord->execute_kw('myDB', 1, 'myPassword',
                        'product.template', 'search_read',
                        array(
                            array(
                            array('name', 'ilike', 'pixma'),
                            array('type', 'ilike', 'product'),
                        ['fields'=>array('name', 'description'), 'limit'=>5]
                     ))); 
?>
```

How can i join the product.template model with product.brand so that i can get data's product brand. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the reference to brand in `fields`.

```
<?php

$db = 'myDB';
$uid = 1;
$password = 'myPassword';

# You will need to include a reference to the Many2one field
# that exists on your product.template record. I'm assuming it's
# called something like "brand" or "brand_id"
$fields = array('name', 'description', 'brand');


$products = $ripcord->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'product.template', 'search_read', array(array(
        array('name', 'ilike', 'pixma'),
        array('type', 'ilike', 'product'),
        ['fields'=> $fields, 'limit'=>5])));
```

Comment: I got it. 
But let's say in the `product.template` contain fields: `id`, `name`, `type`, `brand` and `description`. And in `product.brand` contain fields: `id`,  `brand_name`, `category_brand`, and `price`. Which is `brand` in `product.template` relate with `id` in `product.brand`. I want to show are `name` and `description` from `product.template` and `category_brand` and `price` from `product.brand`. 

 if i just put the `brand` field like you said, it's just show the id's brand. How can I also show the `category_brand` and `price`?

Thank you :)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you have to make multiple requests. So you will pull just the ids from product.brand and make another `search_read` request against that model for it's fields. It's possible to write you're own helper method to use dot notation and automatically pull the relations, but Odoo's api doesn't offer the functionality directly.